# RecyclerView - some variables of one items are empty - don't show item at all

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is there a possibility using the RecyclerView in Android Studio to not show one whole item if there are variables empty that should be shown in that item?

For example if I got 3 variables to be shown in the item, but only 2 of them have a value - don't show the item at all.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The best approach to handle this would be to isolate the data-loading from the data-exhibition. Load the data in an isolated class, than when you have the list of items that have 3 variables use it to update the recyclerview.

Answer (score 1):

There's no supported API for this. The best idea I have is to set the view's height to 0 when you don't want to show it. Here's some code that hides the view at position 3 and shows the others:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = (position == 3) ? 0 : ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);

    // other binding code here
}
```

If your item views aren't using `wrap_content` for their height, then you'd have to set the height to that fixed value. You could use this code to fetch that fixed size:

```
holder.itemView.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.your_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use your own implementation of BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter, you could filter ListView or RecyclerView with holding two lists in your adapter class: one for all values, and one (shown) for filtered values. Also there's no need in hacks like setting some items height to 0 (which may produce problems).

Comment: I agree that filtering the list (and therefore never binding items you don't want to see) is a reasonable approach. I'm curious, though, what problems you're referring to when you say that setting height to zero "may produce problems".

Comment: Ben P., I don't say you can't set view height to 0 or that your example isn't workable. But complex/low-level logic and hacks always may produce problems. I.e. if you do such thing like setting your list element view height to 0dp you'll have to understand your adapter's view binding (do it only in onBindViewHolder or right part of getView methods) and always remember that your list enumeration != what you see.